# Converting UTM coordinates to Lat Long

Tags: coordinate-system, convert, latitude-longitude, utm

I have a series of UTM coordinates in an Excel file that I need to convert to Lat/Long.  They are listed in the spreadsheet as "LONG(XUTM)" and "LAT(YUTM)".  I know the coordinates are located in Bulgaria.  Trying to figure out exactly how I can convert these - so far I'm using tools online and I'm getting lat/longs that put me in the ocean or in sudan or something...

Here are a selection of the coords:

```
LONG(XUTM)  LAT(YUTM)
5400054.968 2262690.795
5410764.956 2279927.441
5406759.683 2282320.619
5402952.243 2277883.785
5412539.46  2258225.544
5425763.452 2287138.979
5437312.03  2250401.825
```

I don't know the zone but from looking at a UTM map I think it would be 35T.  Still not getting expected lat/longs when I do the conversion though.

Comment: Can you narrow down what location this data represents? City?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your comfortable on the command line [cs2cs](https://trac.osgeo.org/proj/wiki/man_cs2cs) is a great way to convert coordinates. You can specify the coordinate system to convert to in from in multiple format, but epsg codes are convenient. To find the EPSG code for your coordinate system of interest look on [spatialreference.org](http://spatialreference.org/), for example see the page for [UTM zone 35n](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84-utm-zone-35n/).

```
cs2cs +init=epsg:32631 +to +init=epsg:4326
```

cs2cs will then accept coordinates on standard input, and print the converted coordinates.

```
cs2cs +init=epsg:32631 +to +init=epsg:4326
2262690.795 5400054.968
25d58'10.167"E  46d23'22.344"N 0.000
```

I tried several UTM zones, and swapping your columns, and I could not find a zone that puts them in Bulgaria, they are either are latitude 15n, or latitude 46n.

Comment: I agree with @Jesse Crocker, your points seem to be in Serbia